# how to find Sub String Using regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

```
UDF2<String, String, Boolean> contains = new UDF2<String, String, Boolean>() {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -5239951370238629896L;
 @Override
     public Boolean call(String t1, String t2) throws Exception {
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(t1);
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile(t2);
        return  p1.toString().contains(p2.toString());
     }
 };
 spark.udf().register("contains", contains, DataTypes.BooleanType);
```

In the above  find a key in other string, if found it `return true` but it returns sub string of `t2` also.

Actual Output:

```
t1 Hello world
t2:Hello
t2 :wo
t2:rl
t2:Hello world
t1 returns all this 3 but i want only hello or world key
```

I try this

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^"+t1+"$");
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^"+t2+"$");
return  p1.toString().contains(p2.toString());
```

But it work if `t2` contains `Helow world` 
i want `Hello OR world` any one is present it `return True` 
Can you please help me to write Reguler Expression

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but basically you don't need regular expression to check whether substring of one string in another, you can just use

```
boolean isSubstring = t1.contains(t2);
```

if `t2` is indeed a **regular expression**, not a regular string, you need to create a `Pattern` object from it (as you did), Then create a `Matcher` on the string which you wish to check, and then check with `Matcher.find()` method

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(t2);
Matcher m = p.matcher(t1);
boolean isSubstring = m.find();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex, you can just use String::contains method, here is a simple example :

```
String line = "Hellow My best world of java";
String str = "Hello world";
String[] spl = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split(" ");
boolean check = true;
for(String s : spl){
    if(!line.contains(s)){
        check = false;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(check ? "Contain all" : "Not contains all");
```

---

The idea is :

1. split your words with space
2. loop throw this results
3. check if the your string contains all this results, if one is not exist break your loop and return false